# SQL Server 2012 Transactional Replication - twin subscriptions on same machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

Server A publishes Pub1, Server B subscribes to Pub1.

Server A and Server B are both SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition, default instances.

When I use Replication Monitor to drop-in a Tracer Token, one publisher-subscriber shows-up passing the token as expected.

When I run `sp_helpsubscription` 'Pub1' on Server A, one subscription shows-up as expected.

When I expand Replication->Local Subscriptions in SSMS on Server B, two identical subscriptions show-up.

What's going on?  Which subscription should I delete at Server B?

Comment: Hi Erik,
try to execute the following query on the subscriber database (the one on server b):

    SELECT distinct publisher, publisher_db, publication, time, transaction_timestamp, subscription_guid
    FROM dbo.MSreplication_subscriptions
    ORDER BY 1,2,3

Comment: @Giova, 2 rows are returned, one for each subscription.  The first 3 columns are identical, the last 3 columns differ.

Answer (score 0):

Giova's query brought into sharper focus the name of the publication; Pub 1 vs. Pub_1, for example.

The difference between the two subscriptions was the under-bar, '_', character in the name of the publication.

The subscription referencing the non-existent publication was deleted.